# Statical and dynamical column in QML TableView

Tags: qt, qml, qtableview

I would like to show in one column static data like data titles and on second column show dynamically populated data from c++ part of program. I want to send dynamical data from qt c++ part as QStringList. Data comes from sql database and i only need static titles on first column and data on second. Any ideas ?

[EDIT] 
I have QStringList passed from c++ with dynamically populated data and Listmodel in QML with names describing each value form QStringList. I want to show both lists in one QML TableView. I wanted to merge them in ListModel like 
`ListElement {
         title: "Part material"
         data: handlecombo.stringmodel4x.at(1).toString}
ListElement {
         title: "Part dimension"
         data: handlecombo.stringmodel4x.at(2).toString}`

But i can't use scripts in listmodel

Comment: Be more precise : what do you want exactly ? what did you tried so far ?

Comment: I can do this as two separate tables but its not elegant way imo